# Left Ideals in $C^*$ algebra

Tags: ideals, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be  $C^*$-algebra, $L$ be a maximal left ideal, $\Lambda(A)= \{ L \subset A\}$, and $rad(A) = \cap_{L \in \Lambda(A)} L$.

[image]

I'm trying to understand this Lemma. But I'm stuck on understanding these points.

1. Why no left ideal admits $e$?
2. Why we can use Zorn's lemma here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If an ideal (left or right) $L$ in a unital algebra $A$ contains the unit, then $L=A$.  So no  ideal (proper, left or right) in a unital algebra can contain the unit.